# YouTube navigate back from video fragment to home fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, animation, android-motionlayout

I want to achieve behavior similar to YouTube navigating behavior when you click on video item, video fragment will open and if you slide down go back to home fragment, I make the animations with MotionLayout but navigating back with animation I don't know how to impalement that, I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

[image: F1 is home fragment]

[image]

Comment: any solution you found bro? @Sami Shorman

Comment: @Fahad-Android Nope bro you can try making activity with motion-layout and host 2 fragments inside it one from a list of videos and one for the media player then make a scene in activity motion-layout when swiping the media player fragment

Comment: That can be done bro, really helpful